# How to clear the session variable in asp.net design source file

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, .net

Session["pageIndex"] this is my variable which is used in all aspx.cs pages

I used

```
$('#btn_click').click(function(){
sessionStorage.removeItem('pageIndex');
)};
```

to clear the session variable in design source file but it doesn't works

help me thanks in advance

Comment: Please share your code. Without code we can't tell what you are doing wrong how you can correct it.

Comment: Please post code for the page. There can be a number of causes for the "broken back button" but without seeing the actual code it is hard to help.

Comment: actually code is written by someone now am just fixing the issue

Comment: i have updated my code @ChetanRanpariya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you throw the page number into the query string, then in the `Page_Load` event, you check for it. If its there, you go to that page directly, otherwise you load the first page.

This should support browser back button functionality taking you to the correct page.

The issue you're experiencing is that ASP.NET is letting you change the page content without changing the url.

Comment: Thank you dude it works well after getting the session pageIndex..How to clear session variable when button click event happens can you please help me @Nate

Comment: @SatG_shanu I recommend that you revert the edit to your question here, and post a new question.